# how is symbian able to support multiple coding languages?

Tags: symbian

How is possible we are able to make applications that run on the Symbian platform using several languages like the J2me framework and the qt framework.

How does Symbian take of executing code written in several languages?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're mixing up several conceptions. First of all, you need to understand that module of execution (your_program.exe) has nothing to do with programming language. Module of execution (executable) consists of so called machine codes. Only machine codes can be executed by CPU.

Programming language conception is a mean to conveniently translate human ideas to machine codes. Actual work of translation is done by a toolchain, which consists of several tools, of which compiler and linker are main. Compiler creates modules of machine code for each module of programming language (*.cpp file for C++, for example). Then linker then takes all of machine code modules from compiler output and create executable from them.

With this in mind, you may easily understand that Symbian C++, Qt or any other languages/dialects code is first processed by tool-chain, and the output is in machine codes, which are the same for different programming languages. Of course, it's possible on any OS, not only Symbian.

Java is a little bit of different story. J2ME code is not translated directly in machine codes. Instead, Java code is translated into a kind of intermediate thing between machine codes and programming language code, so then it can be executed in Java virtual machine on CPUs of different architecture. But the essence is the same: translation of human-readable programming language code into something that can be executed by machine.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask more if something is unclear.

Comment: where is the complier located? Are the compilers of all the different languages built into the OS?Also the JVM for java is located in the os?

Comment: No, Symbian C++ and Qt toolchains (together with compiler) are located on your development PC, not on the phone. You use output of toolchain to create a *.sis file, which can in turn be installed on the phone. It contains executable which can be run directly on the OS, and that executable structure is not depending on the toolchain used - Symbian OS or Qt.
Java is, again, a little bit of different story. You also have a sis file with java code, but Java Virtual Machine (which is responsible for java program execution) is running on a phone, as a part of OS.